# Classifying homeomorphisms of the torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm reading *Automorphisms of Surfaces after Nielsen and Thurston* by Casson and Bleiler, and I'm confused by something in the introductory section where the authors classify the homeomorphisms of a torus.

They say that, "The homeomorphisms of $T^2$ correspond to the elements of the general linear group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as any element $\alpha$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ maps $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to itself and so induces a continuous map $h_\alpha:T^2\to T^2$."

I understand why the map $h_\alpha$ is induced by $\alpha$, but it's not clear to me why every homeomorphism of the torus is induced by some element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Any homeomorphism $f:T^2\to T^2$ certainly lifts to an invertible map $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, but why is $\tilde f$ linear?

Comment: Looks like a misunderstanding. Clearly, there are many more homeomorphisms, uncountably many. Are you sure they didn't factor out some relation, such as "up to isotopy" or so?

Comment: Definitely possible. But I don't see that anywhere in the introduction, which is only 2 pages long. The quote I have above is a direct quote, no paraphrasing, and I figure their use of the word 'correspond' wasn't supposed to be colloquial. I can link to a picture of their work if that would be helpful (and if stack exchange rules allow it).

Comment: Maybe it was a "high-level language" and "corresponds" didnd't really mean a 1-1 correspondence...

Comment: Yea, maybe. Here's a link to the introduction if you're willing and interested to read it for yourself

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/JqhI8

Comment: They are referring to [Nielsen–Thurston classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen–Thurston_classificationd) so you should view it in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying 60589. The book is about the NT classification, yes, but how does that inform this part? Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: I happened to see this post and would like to add a comment, just for the ones who see this later... Since $\mathbb{T}^2$ is a $K(G,1)$ space, the homotopy classes of self-homeomorphisms are in one-to-one correspondence with $\text{Aut}(\pi_1\mathbb{T}^2)\simeq GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and homotopy on a surface implies isotopy, which is in comparison as the Nielsen-Thurston classification the user mentioned above. (I'm just guessing what he or she means...)